# Swift: Tracking User's score

Tags: swift, textlabel

I'm trying to create a Quiz app that consists of two buttons, false and true button. My question is, as I answer more questions in the app, I want the textLabel to keep track of my score. And then when I circle back to the first question again, it should reset. This is my code so far. I'm looking forward to your answers.

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressBar: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet weak var trueButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var falseButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
    
    
    var quizBrain = QuizBrain()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        updateUI()
        progressBar.progress = 0.0
    }
    
    @IBAction func answerButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        let userAnswer = sender.currentTitle
        let userGotItRight = quizBrain.checkAnswer(userAnswer!)
        
        if userGotItRight {
            sender.shortChangeTo(.green)
        } else {
            sender.shortChangeTo(.red)
        }
        
        quizBrain.nextQuestion()
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            self.updateUI()
            
        }
    }
    
    
    func updateUI() {
        

        questionLabel.text = quizBrain.getQuestionText()
        
        trueButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        falseButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        
        progressBar.progress = 33
        
        scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(quizBrain.getScore)"
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any code for it yet? You can create a struct like user

```
struct user {
var score: Int = 0
mutating func answerRight (){
self.score =+ 1 }

mutating func reset (){
self.score = 0 }

}
```

But I see this in your code "Score: (quizBrain.getScore)"
This says that quizBrain should know the score. But you never add a value to it So check your quizBrain and create a function or an object that can track the score and then call it here "if userGotItRight {}"